# Click a dynamically created select to select other dynamic content using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello so I have a fun one.

I am currently working on a small Chrome extension for a side project at my work. The extension is just going to append a div to the right side of the page and provide 'quick-links' with inputs for users. Instead of trying to click through the tree menu, select the correct option then change a textarea. I have buttons on the my extension where they can set the value and click apply. What's happening is we have a web-app that has a bunch of dynamically loaded `<select>`. There's a tree menu that contains links.  When an item in the tree menu gets selected, it will dynamically load a few more divs that contain `<select>`.

What I am trying to do is programatically change the selected option which should in turn fire off another event handled by the web-app to call some dynamic content.

The select will go to the correct value, but the web-app isn't registering that as anything changing.

*****Edited*****
Here is an example of what the page looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/tpkn92o8/6

**Edits below**

The way the web-app works is (the following logic is baked into the web-app and I have no control over this):

1. item in the tree menu is selected.  This will ping home and dynamically load some content into the blue select.
2. Since the blue select gets changed, that triggers the `change` event and the green select to dynamically get loaded.
3. Once again since the green select triggered a `change` event, it will dynamically update the textarea value.

What I want to do is once everything is loaded, I want to be able to change the value of the green select, which should make the web-app trigger the change and update the textarea, i.e.

`$("#dynamic-content-2 select").val('some new value').change()`

Would give us

`<textarea value="some new value"></textarea>`

But unfortunately, the select will get changed but won't trigger the textarea to update

**Second Edits**

```
var updatedVal = 'a new value I get from an array';
window.addEventListener ("load", setupEventHandlers, false);

function setupEventHandlers(){
    var jsInitChecktimer = setInterval (checkForJS_Finish, 111);
    function checkForJS_Finish () {
        // the select I want to manipulate gets loaded when the radio is checked and a different select has a certain value
        if ( document.querySelector("#myRadio:checked") && $("#parentSelect").val() == "100" ) {
            clearInterval (jsInitChecktimer);
            console.log('loaded');

            $("#changeSelect_Button").on("click", function () {

                $("#mySelect").val(updatedVal).change();

            });
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: In your fiddle the element with id **dynamic-content-2** is a `div`, not a `select`. So your code  `$("#dynamic-content-2").val('some new value').change()` would be working on the wrong tag.

Comment: That was just to show the layout of what/where things were more than an actual prototype. Sorry for the confusion there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Since the Chrome Extension is run in a sandboxed environment, it has unreliable results when trying to interact with objects in the DOM.  What I needed to do was inject a script into the page which contained my `change()` event.

Here's the code I run when the content_script.js is loaded by the extension:

```
var injectedCode = 
    'function changeSelect(newVal) { '+
        '$("#pageSelect").val(newVal).change();'+
    '}';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.appendChild(document.createTextNode( injectedCode ));
(document.body || document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
```

And here is the code I inject when my button is clicked:

```
$("#buttonInExtensionDiv").click(function(){
    function injectCode(code){
        var newScript = document.createElement('script');
        newScript.appendChild(document.createTextNode( code ));
        (document.body || document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(newScript);
    }
});
```

*credit for the script above goes to another StackOverflow user. I can't find the link. I just separated it into a function in order to re-use it without clutter.*

**Example**

For basic example, my extension has a div that gets injected onto the page through the content_script.js which contains a button. When that button is clicked I wanted it to change a select that was dynamically added (by the webapp) to the page.  Since the extension is sandboxed it wasn't firing off the change event properly.

**Caveats**

Inside of my extension, the button is tied to a click handler that will call: `injectCode('updateSelect()');`.

Every time I click that button, the extension will append

`<script>injectCode('updateSelect()');</script>`

to the end of the DOM which adds clutter.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign values to the `value` properties of your `option` elements. So change:

```
<option val='load-something-1'>Option 2.1</option>
```

to:

```
<option value='load-something-1'>Option 2.1</option>
```

Or, if you need the custom `val` attribute, then add the `value` attribute as well.

Secondly, you tried the following code:

```
$("#dynamic-content-2").val('some new value').change();
```

... but that changes the value of a `div`. Looking at your fiddle, you should give the `select` (child of this `div`) a value as follows:

```
$("#dynamic-content-2>select").val('some new value').change();
```

and the value you give as argument should correspond to one of the `value` property values of the `option` tags.

If then your web-app listens to the `change` event of the select, it will work.

Here is some `HTML` code inspired by your fiddle:

```
    <div id="dynamic-content-2" class='fifty'>
        <select size="3">
            <option value='load-something-1'>Option 2.1</option>
            <option value='load-something-2'>Option 2.2</option>
            <option value='load-something-3'>Option 2.3</option>    
        </select>
    </div>
```

and some `JavaScript` that demonstrates the workings:

```
// Mimic the web-app, about which we have no information:
$('#dynamic-content-2>select').change(function (e) {
    $("textarea").val('Option ' + (this.selectedIndex+1) + ' was selected.');
});

// On page load, select the second option and trigger the change event
$(function () {
    $('#dynamic-content-2>select').val('load-something-2').change();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've revised my post. I had setup my question wrong. Please have another look at the edited sections :)

Comment: You'll need to find out what the wep-app is responding to. Without that it is only guess-work. You could try to also chain some or all of the following `.focus().mousedown().click().mouseup()` before the `change()`. But if that doesn't make the web-app detect the change, you really need to get into that web-app and find out how it detects the change.

Comment: Ah ok.  I don't know if this helps, but when I execute the $("myselect").val('new val').change() from the developer tools console, it works.  I will try your recommendation in the meantime.

Comment: Make sure that when you run the code, you run it after the web-app has completely loaded, otherwise it might miss the `change` event.

Comment: I have setup the code to fire only when the Select I am trying to change is fully loaded and still am not seeing anything. I think what's happening is the page is fully loaded, but since the select get's generated AFTER that happens, i.e. a link from the tree menu gets clicked, it isn't binding the change event properly. Do you know how I could bind the change event to dynamically loaded selects? I've tried the $('select').on('change',fn(){ }); but I don't know what to do inside of the callback. I've updated my question to include actual code. (Also thanks for all of the help so far!)

Comment: You accidentally requested an update to my answer instead of modifying your question. Could you still update your question?

Comment: I am also a bit confused in that you now want to capture the change event on the `select`. As far as I understood, your original question is about **triggering** the event (for the web-app to respond to), not to **bind** to it yourself, otherwise you will be running in circles. Have I misunderstood? Note that if the wep-app responds well when you manually select an option, then this means the wep-app has no problem in binding itself to the `select` even if it is dynamically created. It is just that it uses a different mechanism than capturing the `change` event, which we do not know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94730/discussion-between-meepz-and-trincot).